# Instagram api throttling on comments (POST) end point

Tags: http-post, instagram, instagram-api, rate-limiting

I'm writing an app that part of it's functions is to write comments to posts on instagram in order to interact with the profile owner.
There might be a lot of comments posted.

I have checked the rate limits (https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) and therefore I will be limiting the requests per hour.

The thing is, it seems like there are limitations on the speed of requests going out to instagram (which I wasn't able to find documentation for).

If I execute a few POST requests too fast I get this error:

> {"meta": {"error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError", "code": 400,
>   "error_message": "It looks like you were misusing this feature by
>   going too fast. You\u2019ve been temporarily blocked from using
>   it."}}

How do I know how much delay is needed between requests? 
How much time will I be blocked?

Comment: What kind of requests were you sending? The documentation (paragraph at the bottom) suggests this is due to spam filtering, not rate limiting. Are you repeatedly sending the exact same comment or posting to the same account?

Comment: Yes, it looks like spam filtering.
My app will post similar or the same comment and may post it to the same account but for different media (pictures).
What are the restrictions for that?

Comment: You aren't going to get Instagram to disclose details on the restrictions for spam, because, if these were spelled out, spammers could use these to effectively circumvent them. Indeed, even if they *were* spelled out, Instagram would reserve the right to change them on the fly as needed. So, basically, try not to look too much like spam.